# ALERT - You're nearing the maximum connections threshold

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

MongoDB alerting maximum number of connections

This alert is coming in my Gmail from quite a few times. This also has come to me in my previous project and I ignored it. I am using a MongoDB in my NEXT.JS project for an ecommerce-clothing site. I am using a shared MongoDB database which has limited connections. After the connections exceed the limits, ig I cannot fetch data from the database as it happened to me previously. I think this happens as I do not close connections after connecting to the database. How can I close a connection successfully after fetching the required data from the database in my NEXT.JS project.

**MONGODB CONNECTION FILE**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const dbConnect = async() => {
    if(mongoose.connection.readyState >= 1){
        return 
    }
    try{
         mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI!)
        console.log("connected")
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
}

export default dbConnect;
```

**API FILE TO FETCH DATA**

```
import dbConnect from "../../libs/mongo";
import product_model from "@/models/product_model"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req:any){
    // try{
        const body = await req.json();

        const { name, images, categoryId, price, colorId, description } = body;

        await dbConnect();

        const data= await product_model.create({
           name,
            price,
            categoryId,
            colorId,
            images, 
            description, 
            });


        return NextResponse.json({data})
}

export async function GET(){
    await dbConnect();
    const product = await product_model.find();
    return NextResponse.json({ product });
}
```